# Best design for a zip code/city many-to-many bridge table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying out a few ideas to build a zip code/cityName table, where I will only be using it one way- given the zip code, return either the primary city name (this is how it will most often be used), or return a list of all valid city names for that zip. The two ideas I had were

1) Make a 3 column table- zip, cityName, and primary. Where the "primary" column is just a boolean that marks whether or not the city in that row is the primary city name for that zip code.

2) Two column table, but the zip code column will be unique. Having a regular "12345" zip for the primary city row, and "12345-1","12345-2", etc for the alternate city names. I was thinking this would make it easier to grab the primary city name, and I could do a LIKE "12345%" to retrieve all city names when needed.

Since I'm really new to database design, I thought one of you may have some insight as to which would be better, or if there's a better third option I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend option 2. You are in some respect "designing" your data to fit your schema, rather than the other way around.

Option 1 is certainly feasible, and I do not see any real drawbacks if you have given all the use cases. Just make sure to add proper keys, indexes and constraints. I can see that you would at least need these:

- Primary key: Zip, CityName (each row is uniquely determined by a Zip/City combination)
- Index: Primary (to be able to find all primary cities)
- Constraint: Only one primary city per zip

Comment: Thanks.  Another idea I had was to merge it with my lat/long table.  I have a separate table with zipID/Lat/Long columns.  What if I use option 1, remove the "Primary" column and add "Lat" and "Long", but only including the data on the primary city name rows, and those columns would be null on alternate city rows.

Comment: Hm, why would you not include lat/lon on non-primary cities? Seems like a useful piece of data, and more importantly, you're getting back to the "designing data instead of schema". Using presense of lat/lon as an indication of primary city is not a good design, to my mind.

Comment: I definitely understand where you're coming from.  The lat/lon will only be used for a radius check given a zip code, so it really won't be used in conjunction with city names.  The alternate city names will only be for restrictions on new addresses into the database (the city name must be one associated with that zip code).

Comment: Still, I would definitely recommend having them separated, and having the primary flag on the table.